# Creating new dynamic folders and generating dynamic file names

Tags: xml, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to utilize VBA to generate a file path that is relevant to content within a presentation. I have presentations that are created and when ready, they need a unique folder and name.

Ideally, I'd like to create a custom file path that starts at (C:\DSS_Test\Starting_folder), where the company name would be added to the folder path. Within that folder path, it would have the file name with the company name and case. So, it would be something like \Customer\Customer_Name-Case_Number.pptm.

This unique info is pulled from two separate text boxes on the same slide.  I also need to be able to account for any spaces/characters for saving purposes.

I feel like I'm in over my head, as I cannot seem to get off the ground. I've scoured through various forums and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Here's what I have below. It errors out at the `.value`  within the last line, giving a compile error: method or data member not found. This makes me think that the path is incorrect as well. ANY help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
Sub Save()
Dim objPresentation As Presentation
Dim objSlide1 As Slide
Dim objTextBox1 As Shape

Dim objSlideA As Slide
Dim objTextBoxA As Shape
Dim objTextBoxB As Shape

Set objPresentation = ActivePresentation
Set objSlide1 = objPresentation.Slides("Coverletter")
Set objTextBox1 = objSlide1.Shapes.Item("TextBox3")

Set objSlideA = objPresentation.Slides("Infokey")
Set objTextBoxA = objSlideA.Shapes.Item("dsscust1stname")
Set objTextBoxB = objSlideA.Shapes.Item("case")
Dim Path As String

Path = "C:\DSS Test\Starting folder\.SaveAs objTextBoxA.Value & objTextBoxB.Value"

MkDir Path

With Application.ActivePresentation
    .SaveAs objTextBoxA.Value & objTextBoxB.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: How exactly do you think `"C:\DSS Test\Starting folder\.SaveAs objTextBoxA.Value & objTextBoxB.Value"` is going to work? `.SaveAs` is an Application method, and when embedded in quotes `objTextBoxA` is a simple string of text, not a variable, and so is the remainder of that part of the path variable. And why are you going to the trouble of building `Path` when you're not using it in the actual `.SaveAs` call?

Comment: In addition to Ken's suggestions, understand that if your text boxes are ActiveX objects, you'd use e.g. objTextBoxA.OLEFormat.Object.Value to get the text. If they're regular PPT text boxes, you'd use objTextBoxA.TextFrame.TextRange.Text